# Unity URP lit shader: One material different 'tinted' objects

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader

I'm very new on shader programming and would be interested in **modify urp lit shader** to support setting properties in objects with MaterialPropertyBlock on runtime.

The objective is to have several objects with the **same material** 'tinted' with a **different color each one**.

Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't know shader programming but if you want several objects sharing a material to be tinted with different colors a script like this might work :

```cs
public class Tint : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Color TintColor;

    [Range(0,1)]
    public float TintIntensity = 0.5f;
        
    private void OnEnable()
    {
        Material material = GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material;
        material.color = Color.Lerp(material.color,TintColor,TintIntensity);
    }

}
```

Comment: This will leak one material object per call. You should be using MaterialPropertyBlocks: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MaterialPropertyBlock.html